# problem with Google Search Rest ful API return max 64 result

Tags: asp.net

I m using Google restful API for Search  .Here is my restful request

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&start=0&rsz=large&q=site: http://www.google.com/ Apple

But when i am searching with "http://www.google.com/"  it returns only 64 result.
Can any one tell me how i can get more than 64 result by using this RESTFUL API from google.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it does. Use *start* parameter in the *url* to implement paging.

for example, `&start=64` in your request URI should return the next page.

### Reference:

[Using REST to Invoke the API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/using_rest.html#query-params)

Comment: I done with &start=64 this but it return the null result  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&start=64&rsz=large&q=site: http://www.google.com/ apple

Comment: That maybe because you have not used an API key. Look at the given reference for more details on how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/blog-search/v1/reference).

> **Important note: Maximum number of search results**
>
> The Google Blog
>   Search API allows a maximum of 64 results on 8 pages. There is no way
>   to get more than 64 results.

Comment: your answer is about Google **Blog** Search API, but the op just asked about the general search api